# Created a Database with a shell script, however user not permitted to log in

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-rest-framework, psql

When I attempt to start my djangoRESTapi I get an error saying

`FATAL:  role "admin3" is not permitted to log in`

everytime I attempt to use manage.py

The current script.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
psql -c "DROP DATABASE $sqlProject;"
psql -c "DROP ROLE $projectAdmin;"
#createdb -E UTF-8 $sqlProject

psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $sqlProject;"
psql -c "CREATE ROLE $projectAdmin WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD '$projectPassword';"
psql -c "ALTER ROLE $projectAdmin SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';"
psql -c "ALTER ROLE $projectAdmin SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';"
psql -c "ALTER ROLE $projectAdmin SET timezone TO 'UTC';"
psql -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $sqlProject TO $projectAdmin;"
psql -c "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE $sqlProject TO $projectAdmin;"
psql -c "\q"
```

Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it as CREATE ROLE not CREATE USER.

That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createuser.html

> CREATE USER is now an alias for CREATE ROLE. The only difference is
>   that when the command is spelled CREATE USER, LOGIN is assumed by
>   default, whereas NOLOGIN is assumed when the command is spelled CREATE
>   ROLE.

so as you found yourself, either use `create user`, or add `login` to your script:

```
db=# create role canlogin login;
CREATE ROLE
Time: 18.688 ms
db=# \q
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ psql so -U canlogin
Timing is on.
Pager usage is off.
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.
```